# CalledProcessError: tabula-py error message when reading PDF file

Tags: python, spyder, tabula-py

I'm trying to read a PDF file with tabula-py in Spyder using the below code:

```
import tabula
df = tabula.read_pdf("test.pdf")
df
```

However when I run this I get the error:

CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF8', '-jar', 'path to tabula jar', '--pages', '1', '--guess', path to PDF file']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Similar questions have been solved by upgrading to Java 8, but I'm already using Java 8 and Spyder has it in it's environment variables. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar issue, it was down to an Java pointing to an old version of Java I had installed.